# How to make an external log using Excel VBA?

Tags: events, logging, excel, vba

The code has been updated to reference the changes below.

This log system create an external document for Excel called Log.txt, it will create a line in the log.txt file that looks like this:

> 11:27:20 AM Matthew Ridge changed cell $N$55 from ss to

This will not tell you if someone entered a new line of code into the sheet, but if the code demands an answer, it will tell you what cell that answer is in. This codes below should work for both Mac and PC systems combined. If people find it doesn't please say.

This code was created with the help of people here, and other forms, so I can't take sole proprietorship of the document, but I can take ownership of the concept. So thanks to those who helped, without this there now wouldn't be a viable logging system for Excel in my opinion ;)

BTW, before anyone freaks out and asks where does this code go, it isn't obvious to the general/new end user. You need to go to the **[Developer Tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx)** open it up, click on Visual Basic, and when the new window opens look for Microsoft Excel Object; under that folder should be your workbook. You can either put it under ThisWorkbook or inside any of the sheets by double clicking on the sheet you want the code to be in.

Once the sheet is open on the right panel, you will see Option Explicit, if you don't it is best if you activate it by making sure the **Require Variable Declaration** is checked. This is found at the Visual Basic window again, and follow this path:

**Tools**-> **Options** -> **Editor**.

If it is checked then you have no worry, if not then you check it. Option Explicit is a good thing for you code, it forces you to declare variables, which is a good practice to begin with.

After it is verified, you can copy the code below to either paste it in your Workbook, or a specific sheet depending on your needs.

### Version 2.01

```
Option Explicit
Dim PreviousValue

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sLogFileName As String, nFileNum As Long, sLogMessage As String

    sLogFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Log.txt"

 On Error Resume Next ' Turn on error handling
    If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
        ' Check if we have an error
        If Err.Number = 13 Then
           PreviousValue = 0
        End If
        ' Turn off error handling
        On Error GoTo 0
        sLogMessage = Now & Application.UserName & " changed cell " & Target.Address _
        & " from " & PreviousValue & " to " & Target.Value

        nFileNum = FreeFile                         ' next file number
        Open sLogFileName For Append As #nFileNum   ' create the file if it doesn't exist
        Print #nFileNum, sLogMessage                ' append information
        Close #nFileNum                             ' close the file
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target(1).Value
End Sub
```

As time goes by, I will attempt to update this code to add more features to it as I deem fit.

Again thanks to all that helped, it is greatly appreciated to make this possible.

Comment: @JasonClark gave you a good answer.  Thinking more broadly, if multiple cells are changed at once, do you want to log that?

Comment: If logging is enabled from the start of the workbook's use, you shouldn't need to capture the "old" value, since you should have a record of all entered values for every cell. Then you can address Doug's >1 cell scenario just by looping through `Target.Cells`

Comment: Matt- the only difference between Windows and Mac versions is the line that sets `sLogFileName`, correct?  You can create a single version of the code that works on both platforms by replacing that line with `sLogFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Log.txt".  Application.PathSeparator will return "\" on Windows and ":" on Mac.  Thanks to Doug for the reference.

Comment: Sweet I'll update this when i get to work.

Comment: Ok, quick question for those in the know, is there a way to make this script work with multiple changes done at once? So instead of one cell change at a time, multiple cell changes at a time?

Comment: If I add this code to my ThisWorkbook-code nothing happens. It will work if I copy it to one of my sheets though. How can I make it apply Workbook wide or only for specific sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when the you enter the merged cells, the value put into PreviousValue (in `Worksheet_SelectionChange`) is an array of all of the merged cells, which you can't compare to the the new value.  When `Worksheet_Change` is fired on the edit, the target is only the top-left cell of the merged range.  So let's just track that cell for merged ranges.  Replace your `Worksheet_SelectionChange` with the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target(1).Value
End Sub
```

Disclaimer:  This was tested on Excel for Mac 2011 as I don't have access to Excel for Windows at the moment, but I'm pretty sure that it will work on Excel for Windows as well.

Comment: That will work in Windows.  You could simplify and say `PreviousValue = Target(1).Value` without the IF/ELSE.

Comment: Thanks @DougGlancy.  Much better.  Fixed.

Comment: I'll test this when I get to work, but I do have a question Jason, you tested this on a Mac, which I am now typing on now as well. Did the code create a log on your computer? Or no? I only ask because I've only tested this script on a PC so far.

Comment: Worked on the mac with one change: `sLogFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\OpenOrderLog.txt"` became `sLogFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & ":OpenOrderLog.txt"` (note the colon); presumably because Excel Mac is still a Carbon app under the covers, and ThisWorkbook.Path returns a value like `"Macintosh HD:Users:jclark"`.  I haven't checked to see if Excel VBA offers a platform-independent way of concatenating paths.  Still haven't gotten my sea-legs with Excel for Mac.

Comment: @JasonClark, in Windows Excel it's Application.PathSeparator

Comment: This works perfectly now, thanks a lot for the help this script is going to be used a lot I have a feeling in my future sheets.

Comment: Ok, quick question for those in the know, is there a way to make this script work with multiple changes done at once? So instead of one cell change at a time, multiple cell changes at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Matt Ridge - I know you asked for a solution regarding multiple changes done at once, and i'm only 3 years to late, but here it is :).
I've made some slight modifications to the original code, but this will handle merged cells and log multiple changes to cells.

```
    Option Explicit 
Dim PreviousValue()
```

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    Dim sLogFileName As String, nFileNum As Long, sLogMessage As String, r As Long

`sLogFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Log.txt" 


 'Check all cells for changes, excluding D4 D5 E5 M1 etc
For r = 1 To Target.Count 
    If Target(r).Value <> PreviousValue(r) And Intersect(Target(r), Range("D4,D5,E5,M1")) Is Nothing Then 
         ' Check if we have an error
        If Err.Number = 13 Then 
            PreviousValue(r) = 0 

        End If 
         ' Turn off error handling
         'On Error GoTo 0
         'log data into .txt file
        sLogMessage = Now & " " & Application.UserName & " changed cell " & Target(r).Address _ 
        & " in " & ActiveSheet.Name & " from " & "'" & PreviousValue(r) & "' to '" & Target(r).Value & "'" & " in workbook " & ThisWorkbook.Path & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Name 

        nFileNum = FreeFile ' next file number
        Open sLogFileName For Append As #nFileNum ' create the file if it doesn't exist
        Print #nFileNum, sLogMessage ' append information
        Close #nFileNum ' close the file
    End If 
Next r 
End Sub 


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) 
Dim i As Long 

 'looks at the uppermost cell (incase cells are merged)

Redim PreviousValue(1 To Target.Count) 
For i = 1 To Target.Count 
    PreviousValue(i) = Target(i).Value 
Next i      
    End sub`

Answer (score 1):

one year later i modified the Code from Matthew - now it tracks changes by copy/paste or tracking down the mouse too, thanks Matthew for the good idea!:

```
'Paste this into a Module:

Option Explicit

'SheetArray to hold the old values before any change is made
Public aSheetArr() As Variant


'helperfunctions for last row and last col of a given sheet:

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
'get last row of a given worksheet
sh.EnableAutoFilter = False
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
'get last col of a given worksheet
sh.EnableAutoFilter = False
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


'Paste this into the workbook_Open method of your workbook (initializing the sheetarray)
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lRow As Long

Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Sheets(1)

lCol = LastCol(wks)
lRow = LastRow(wks)


aSheetArr = wks.Range(wks.Cells(1, 1), wks.Cells(lRow, lCol)) 'read the Range from the whole Sheet into the array


End Sub



'Paste this into the tablemodule - area where you want to log the changes:


Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'logging all the changes in a worksheet - also the copy/past's and track down's over ceveral cells

    Dim sLogFileName As String, nFileNum As Long, sLogMessage As String, r As Long


sLogFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Log.txt"


 'Check all cells for changes, excluding D4 D5 E5 M1 etc
For r = 1 To Target.Count
    'compare each cell with the values from the old cell
    If Target(r).value <> aSheetArr(Target(r).Row, Target(r).Column) Then
         ' Check if we have an error
        If Err.Number = 13 Then
            PreviousValue(r) = 0

        End If
         ' Turn off error handling
         'On Error GoTo 0
         'log data into .txt file
        sLogMessage = Now & " " & Application.UserName & " changed cell " & Target(r).Address _
        & " in " & ActiveSheet.Name & " from " & "'" & aSheetArr(Target(r).Row, Target(r).Column) & "' to '" & Target(r).value & "'"

        'set the values in the array to the changed ones
        aSheetArr(Target(r).Row, Target(r).Column) = Target(r).value

        nFileNum = FreeFile ' next file number
        Open sLogFileName For Append As #nFileNum ' create the file if it doesn't exist
        Print #nFileNum, sLogMessage ' append information
        Close #nFileNum ' close the file
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```