# Last modified user name and timein excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a shared excel file used by 6 people. There are multiple rows with data pertaining to each user. I need a (either through macro or excel functions) to find who modified a particular row.

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an external log using Excel VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403517/how-to-make-an-external-log-using-excel-vba)

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-951bdf89-9ee6-4777-b31e-33ad0f594d18